# Different output of NSDate from NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm having some problems with `NSDate`, actually I only need this to verify that it is a valid date, since if it's an invalid date, the `date` instance would return nil. But

```
NSString *textValue = @"13/12/2014";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

// this should cause the output to have no time
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle]; 
formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[formatter setCalendar:[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:textValue];
```

The result of `date` is `2015-01-12 00:00:00 +0000`

What I expect the result should be: `nil`

Comment: You cannot use setDateFormat and setTimeStyle simultaneously as setDateFormat sets custom date format.

Comment: If I remove the setTimeStyle, the date gets nil, always nil even if it's a valid date

Comment: No, if you remove setTimeStyle your date will be 2015-01-12 00:00:00 +0000. And what you want in NSDate ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be nil? How is 13 a valid month?

Comment: No, 13 would be 1st, 14 would be 2nd.. and so on .. it will modules the value with 12.

Comment: Then I can't use `NSDate` to validate a date string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55357/discussion-between-dipaksonara-and-ironwind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *textValue = @"1/12/2014"; 
NSString *textValue1 = @"15/12/2014"; 
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"]; 
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:textValue]; 
NSLog(@" >> %@ ",date);
NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:textValue1]; 
NSLog(@" >> %@ ",date);
```